# How to make this method independently?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

```
private static ArrayList mMyArray;

public void patchUsersExceptCurrentUser(String name) {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    query.whereNotEqualTo("username", name);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                    mMyArray.add(user.getUsername());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I want to use private ArrayList mMyArray not static

I've heard that only final variable can access in anonymous inner class

So then can't I use this method independently?

Comment: make mMyArray non static. It should work.

Comment: If you want to send callback to caller class after the action done, you can create an Interface and you can send back to the caller class

Comment: If accessed from inner class it needs to be `final` or a class field (which is your case). So it doesn't need to be static as @Charu said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public void patchUsersExceptCurrentUser(String name,ParseListener listener) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereNotEqualTo("username", name);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    listener.onSucess(objects);
                }
                else{
                    listener.onError(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public interface ParseListener{
        void onSucess(List<Object>objects);
        void onError(ParseException e);
    }
```

Then you can call this function everywhere, like this:

```
patchUsersExceptCurrentUser("Example", new ParseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSucess((List<Object>objects) {
        myArray = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ParseException e) {
        //show error
    }
});
```

Comment: Even you can send the param FindCallback instead creating a new interface example patchUsersExceptCurrentUser("id",new FindCallback....)